# Warming IP - Different Domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability

What is the best practice concerning the use of different private domains (consequently sender profiles) configured with the Sender Authentication Package in Marketing Cloud? I mean: I should configure emails used for newsletter and DEM manually sent by users and triggered emails automatically sent through API call from other systems.
Salesforce recommends for new client of Salesforce Marketing Cloud to warm the IP.

In this phase it is possible to find spam traps, blocking issues and so on; in order to solve them, you should build up sending history (and consequently trust with regard to domains) starting from a smart size and then continuing to double volume from week to week. These issues could give delays to send email from MC, so I was wondering if it could be a good solution to create two domains: one used only for newsletter and another for triggered. In this way I should probably not have problems in deliverability related to triggered sends.
Could you confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

Your IP warming process is very surgical and it requires some detailed information in order to really outlay a plan. Ultimately the idea is that you build up your sender reputation with the ISP's on your sender IP so it won't get blocked.

A proper warming plan can consists of several pieces of information

- Send volume
- Engagement
- Are you transitioning from another ESP or are you simply adding another IP
- Segmentation

In order to properly warm an IP you will have to have enough through put, each ISP has their own formula and the SFMC deliverability team should be able to share that with you. You will need to segment out your domains (gmail, yahoo, etc.) each has their own threshold and it could look something like this week 1 - gmail 20K, yahoo 20K, aol - 10k; week 2 gmail - 40K, yahoo 40K, aol 20k. So you will have to segment your lists according to those specs and in addition you would want to send to your highest engagers as they can speed up the process some.

I would assume that your "triggered" sends are transactional? or are they simply action based? either way it wouldn't matter since the initiation of send is irrelevant since you are needing to build up your IP.

If you are using another system, I would route your highest engaged, segmented by ISP to the warming IP and keep the others in the old system until you warmed.

Also be sure to practice proper list hygiene which is what can cause your spam traps, blocking issues and delay your warming process. An ideal time span should be between 6 - 8 weeks. If you do everything correctly you can start seeing positive results in as fast as 4 weeks.

So when you say creating 2 domains, not sure exactly what you mean? Anytime you are using a new IP it has to be warmed otherwise you run into issues regardless of the type email you send.

Comment: Hi @dmcs14db, I confirm you that the triggered sends are transactional. 
Creating 2 domains: I mean that I should configure two domains (e.g. '@test.com and '@newsletteremail.com') in MC, but they are referred to the same IP or there is a different IP for each one?
Because I noticed that if you use the same domain and you have issues of deliverability sending commercial emails, you will have consequences on the deliverability related to transactional emails.
For this reason I was wondering if it was a better creating two different domains.